# How to create a "choice" attribute in Documentum 7.1

Tags: documentum

In my Documentum object type, I want to create a "direction" attribute that can have the values "north", "south", "east", "west".

So in the Documentum Administrator tool, in my object type's "Properties" dialog I selected the "Attribute" tab, pressed the "Add" button, and got this screen:

[image]

As you can see, it only lets me select Boolean, String, Integer, ID, Time, Double.

Using the "String" type sounds loosy, as it offers no other available validation than string size. Or is there a hidden way to add some kind of conditional value assistance that would restrict choices to a fixed list?

Note: I can't use Documentum Composer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by these DQL queries:

```
ALTER TYPE test_type ADD direction STRING(16) (SET "label_text"='My selectable attribute')
ALTER TYPE test_type MODIFY attribute1 (VALUE ASSISTANCE IS LIST ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west') IS COMPLETE) PUBLISH
```

It is possible to execute them in Documentum Administrator in **Tools** -> **DQL Editor**.